# MySQL dynamic order

Tags: mysql, sql

In general, all I need to do is to order a MySQL table.
But, it has to be a "smart" order and I would like to hear your opinions.

There is a table of `customers`

```
id, name, email, phone, country, language, registration_time
```

There is another table which holds the `skills` of sales managers as numeric values -

```
sales_manager_id, skill_type, skill_name, skill_value
               7, language  , English   , 5
```

Which means that manager number 7 speaks English on level 5.
Every sales manager can have multiple skills.

Now, I want to order the customers table by **country, language and registration_time** (in this exact order) for a specific sales manager in such a way that the top rows will be from a country in which this sales manager has highest skills, after this by language in which he has the highest skills and after this by registration time.

Do you have any suggestions? The biggest problem is that this query should be simple and readable as much as possible because there would be modifications in the future and I don't want to deal with enormous queries.

Comment: Add some sample data, and show us the result you expect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume I understand your problem. If not please correct me, else here is my solution.

I did a few changes to your tabels in order to test the query and you can test my solution like I did here: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6baf/19)

(1) You need to `JOIN` your `customers` table two times with the `skills` table - first for the `country` skill and second for the `language` skill of a sales manager:

```
select *
from customers
join skills as country_skills on country_skills.skill_name = customers.country
join skills as language_skills on language_skills.skill_name = customers.language
```

(2) You need to restrict your results for just the sales manager you want, e.g. sales manager with `id` = 11:

```
where country_skills.sales_manager_id = 11
and language_skills.sales_manager_id = 11
```

(3) The 'dynamic' order you want:

```
order by country_skills.skill_value desc, language_skills.skill_value desc, regTime desc
```

This would be my complete query:

```
select *
from customers
join skills as country_skills on country_skills.skill_name = customers.country
join skills as language_skills on language_skills.skill_name = customers.language
where country_skills.sales_manager_id = 11
and language_skills.sales_manager_id = 11
order by country_skills.skill_value desc, language_skills.skill_value desc, regTime desc
```

So you got all `customers` sorted by `country` skills of a specific sales manager > `language` skills of a specifiy sales manager > `regTime` of `customer`.
This query ignores `customers` with a `country` or `language` the sales manager got no skill... you can avoid that with a `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: WOW!!! this seems exactly what I was looking for! :)
I want to believe there won't be any edge-cases.
Thank you very much! Genius!